# How can I validate if the string follows a Key=Value pattern?

Tags: java

I have a string of the format, `{Key=value, Key=value.....}` for which I have to write a validator. The above key-value are separated by space `{Key=value, Key=value, Key=value.....}`.
I am completely new to regex but referring to one of the answers in Stack overflow I have written:

```
Boolean check = Pattern.matches("(\\{+)?(\\w+)?=(\\w+)?,?","string to be validated");
```

But the solution is not working.

It is also possible that the expected string could either be `empty()` or of the exact type `<null>`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use a grouping construct to be able to repeat a sequence of patterns. Like `text.matches("(?:\\{\\w+=\\w+(?:,\\w+=\\w+)*})?")`. You can't check if an object is *null* with regex, regex only works with strings.

Comment: Using matches you should match the whole string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just tried 
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\{\\w+=\\w+(?:,\\w+=\\w+)*}","{A=B, C=D}")); 
but it didn't worked

Comment: You added spaces to the sample text in the question, so you need `text.matches("(?:\\{\\w+=\\w+(?:\\s*,\\s*\\w+=\\w+)*})?")`

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you please suggest an example for above string?

Comment: You can use a regex tester like https://regex101.com/r/vIEJDD/1 to see the match. Using matches, you should match the whole string.

Comment: [This is my regex suggestion demo](https://regex101.com/r/vIEJDD/3).

Comment: @Thefourthbird your solution is working perfectly fine for me but I just realized that sometime key value are in form of "{Key=Value,Key=key=value}" as well. Can you please suggest, how can we handle such scenarios as well?

Comment: @MayurJunior - Why don't you simply split the string on `,` and then check if each element in the resulting array matches `\w+\s*=\s*\w+`?

Comment: @MayurJunior That is an odd looking key value pair, but like this would match it https://regex101.com/r/axQStv/1

Comment: LiveandLetLive your solution is the generic one and will work for all the cases but its too lengthy. I just wanted to validated the whole string in single line.
@Thefourthbird the solution which you provided only work for {Key=value, Key=value} i.e. 2 pairs only but my string can contain "n" numbers of such pairs(which was my initial question). Could you please provide me the single line validation for such string?

Comment: @MayurJunior - You can put the whole logic in a function. I've updated the answer accordigly.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string on `\s*,\s*` and then check if each element in the resulting array matches `\w+\s*=\s*\w+`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "{Key1=value1, Key2=value2}", "{Key=Value,Key=key=value}" };

        boolean valid = true;
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + (!isValid(s) ? "false" : "true"));
        }
    }

    static boolean isValid(String str) {
        boolean valid = true;
        String regex = "\\w+\\s*=\\s*\\w+";
        String[] entries = str.replaceAll("[\\{\\}]", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for (String entry : entries) {
            if (!entry.matches(regex)) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Key1=value1, Key2=value2} => true
{Key=Value,Key=key=value} => false
```

**Note:**

1. `\s*,\s*` specifies [zero or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) whitespace characters followed by a comma which in turn may be followed by zero or more whitespace characters.
2. `\w+\s*` specifies one or more word characters followed by zero or more whitespace characters.